# CPT: if more than X images are in post, use pagination

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, pagination

On my website, I have a custom post type ("foto's"). It contains photo albums which are fetched from Facebook with Facebook Photo Fetcher (plugin). This works great. Unfortunately, this plugin does not allow for pagination. On pages that contain a lot of images this can cause problems (verrrrryyy long load times), such as [here](http://www.denotenbalkers.be/fotos/2013-kamp-deel-1/).

Because I am using a CPT it seems possible to me to use pagination. Unfortunately I have never used pagination before and I have no idea how to implement it. Is it in the declaration of the cpt, or is it a different function? And how could I make it work only when posts have more than X images?

My guess would be to create a template `single-fotos.php` which differs from the default one in that it uses pagination. I do not know how to display pagination when there is more than X images though.

### EDIT 1

Building on Matthew's answer, I tried a couple of things. It seems better to edit the plugin, rather than trying building a custom post type.

I added the following lines:

```
// Look for Next page tag in starttag
        if( preg_match('/next=(\d+)/', $retVal['startTag'], $matches) )      $retVal['next']      =$matches[1];

...

// Add default value of next to defaults array
            $defaults = array('cols'    => 6,               //Number of columns of images (aka Number of images per row)
                              ...
                              'next'    => 42);               // Can be any number, but preferably a multitude of 'more'

...

// Output photos AND other tags such as more tag and next page
    foreach($photos as $photo)
        {
            //Output this photo (must get rid of [], or WP will try to run it as shortcode)
            ...
            $link = '<a rel="shadowbox[' . $aid . ']" class="fbPhoto" href="'.$photo->source . '" title="'.$caption_with_br.' " ><img src="' . $photo->picture . '" alt="" /></a>';
            $retVal['content'] .= "<dl class='gallery-item' style=\"width:$itemwidth%\">";
            $retVal['content'] .= "<dt class='gallery-icon'>$link</dt>";
            ...
            $retVal['content'] .= "</dl>\n";

            //Move on to the next row?
            if( $params['cols'] > 0 && ++$i % $params['cols'] == 0 ) $retVal['content'] .= "<br style=\"clear: both\" />\n\n";
            //Insert a more tag?
            if( $params['more'] > 0 && $i == $params['more'] ) $retVal['content'] .= "<!--more-->\n\n";
            //Insert a next page tag?
            if( $params['next'] > 0 && $i == $params['next'] ) $retVal['content'] .= "<!--nextpage-->\n\n";
        }
        if( $i%$params['cols'] != 0 ) $retVal['content'] .= "<br style=\"clear: both\" />\n\n";
        $retVal['content'] .= "</div>\n";
```

The problem with this is, that the nextpage-tag is only rendered once! After 42 photos (default) the next-tag is inserted, but after the following 42 photos it isn't rendered again. I suppose that is quite normal, but I am not familiar enough with PHP to accomplish that it is rendered every multiplication of the value given (or if not, default value) starting from n=1. How can this be done?

### EDIT 2

Note that this should work in combination with a `more` tag and that pagination oughtn't show in the snippet. So I do **not** want [image: this] in a snippet. Also comments and the respond field should only be placed on the last page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$u = 0;
foreach($photos as $photo) {
$u++;

...

  if( ($params['next'] > 0 && $u == $params['next']) ) {
    $retVal['content'] .= "<!--nextpage-->\n\n";
    $u = 0;
  }
```

### EDIT (explaination)

in the code posted by OP `$params['next'] > 0 && $i == $params['next']` assuming `$i` is incremented every foreach cycle (this is not visible in the code, but it can be intuited) when `$i > $params['next']` this not work and the next content is added once.

In my code, using `$u = 0` after adding `<!--nextpage-->\n\n` it should work because $u is incremented again by foreach so my code `if( $params['next'] > 0 && $u == $params['next'] ) {` should works for every multiple of $params['next'].

Comment: This seems to work all right but it has two issues: pagination [shows](http://www.denotenbalkers.be/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Knipsel.png) in a snippet even when the `next` tag is placed after the more tag.
And comments are shown on every page of the multipage post, and I want them only on the last page.

Comment: But `more` is always passed. It makes sure that on an [archive](http://www.denotenbalkers.be/fotos/) page only the 6 first photos are shown as an axcerpt. The problem then is that the pagination is shown there.

Comment: Sorry. I think this can be solved with an `if ( ! is_archive() )` before you print the pagination and the comments template. But in your code I don't see where is the code that print pagination and comments. Maybe you can use this if statement also for limiting `foreach($photos as $photo) {` to loop only `$param['more']` times

Comment: That won't work because the plugin works in such a way that it generates a HTML document as soon as you save a post. No PHP rendering of the plugin happens after that when you load a page. So `is_archive` won't work.

Comment: Now I have understand. (Sorry, I don't know the plugin) Can you give the full output of print_r($retVal) so I can work on it without installing the plugin?

Comment: Do you mean the HTML output it generates? I don't know where I would print the `$retVal`.

Comment: I have get a deeper look to the plugin file. You say you edit plugin. What function you edit? `fpf_fetch_album_content`? If so, after the foreach loop ends, just put `print_r($retVal); die()`; After update a post that contain a facebook album you should see the dump of $retval array. **Of course this should be done in a local install, if you have it**.

Comment: `Array
(
    [cover] => https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/s720x720/524519_510362335677578_85458216_n.jpg
    [count] => 120
    [content] => "(the output)")`

Comment: yes, but... I want to see if the output contains already the pagination and comment link or they are added in the template file.

Comment: Oooooh. They are added in a template file somewhere. I already solved the comments problem though. But can't seem to solve the pagination.

Comment: I think pagination is added somewhere in template or via a filter. so search for 'wp_link_pages' in your template files and then wrap it inside `if ( ! is_archive() )`

Comment: Oh, fixed it. I indeed had to put a conditional `!is_archive` in `content.php`. Thanks again. Will mark as correct!

Comment: You are welcome. This answer made ​​me sweat... :)

Comment: I'll award the bounty as soon as I can. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this plugin, but in looking at the source, I *think* you could do something like this **(EDIT: This doesn't work, because the plugin bails if there is more than one tag per post, see below for a similar approach)**:

```
<!--FBGallery2 1234567890123456789 start=0 max=20 --><!--/FBGallery2-->

<!--nextpage-->

<!--FBGallery2 1234567890123456789 start=20 max=20 --><!--/FBGallery2-->

<!--nextpage-->

<!--FBGallery2 1234567890123456789 start=40 max=20 --><!--/FBGallery2-->

<!--nextpage-->

<!--FBGallery2 1234567890123456789 start=60 max=20 --><!--/FBGallery2-->

<!--nextpage-->

<!--FBGallery2 1234567890123456789 start=80 max=20 --><!--/FBGallery2-->
```

Then use [page links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Page-Links) to paginate the post.

The next step would be to add an action onto `wp_insert_post_data` before the plugin does (using a lower priority number, like 5) and intercept a more generic version of the tag (without pagination). Run an API lookup before the plugin does to find out the number of items, then programmatically break it up like above.

### Edit

As noted in the comments, the plugin doesn't recognize more than one tag per post. Let's take a different approach then. The "magic tag" it uses allows for columnizing. It counts the number of "cells" and inserts a `<br style="clear: both" />`. If you don't need that line break (since you could use pure CSS to accomplish the same thing), you can replace it with the `<!--nextpage-->` tag. Here's an example of doing that:

```
function wpse_100654_split_fb_album( $content ) {
    return str_replace( '<br style="clear: both" />', '<!--nextpage-->', $content );
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'wpse_100654_split_fb_album', 15 );
```

If you do need that line break, then count out the number of rows per page you want, and replace every n<sup>th</sup> line break with the nextpage tag.

Comment: This all sounds like a good plan, but I don't think I can implement this by myself without some extra explanation.

The action would go in functions.php I suppose, but I have no idea what to do in that action. Also, your example code won't work because the plugin only supports one gallery per post.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @BramVanroy. Check out my edits above for an even easier solution.

Comment: I completely looked over this! I have been busy with this, but this doesn't work. I cannot leave out the clear-tag (responsive design that completely relies on that clear tag), but I think there is an easy solution to my problem. See my edit in the main post. Thanks again!

Comment: @BramVanroy Before you start editing the plugin, have you tried using self-clearing nodes instead of a clear tag? https://www.google.com/search?q=clearfix

Comment: If you look at the source code of this page: http://www.denotenbalkers.be/fotos/2013-fietstocht-paalse-plas/ You can see that the plugin does not generate containers for each row. This makes it hard to apply any clearfix solution that works crossbrowser. If you do know one, please do share.

Comment: Also see my new edit